# ScrollView not scroll smoothly

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I am developing online store application, i used bottom navigation menu and fragments to separate the pages of my online store , in my main fragment i have one scrollview that contains one image slider and two horizontal recycler views that used to show newest and special products.
every thing id good but

**my really strange problem is that when i run application in my android phone the scrollview has really really bad performance, it scrolls really slowly and not smoothly.**

i tried many ways to solve this problem ( but unfortunately none of them could solve my problem ) :
- i tried to remove image slider library
- i taught maybe images and bitmaps are the main cause of this bad performance but after i removed all images nothing changed !!!

and here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f6f6f6"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp" />

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
                android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
                android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
                app:piv_animationType="worm"
                app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
                app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
                app:piv_padding="8dp"
                app:piv_radius="4dp"
                app:piv_selectedColor="@color/golden_vip"
                app:piv_unselectedColor="#d1d1d1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/special_products_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="#f1f1f1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="محصولات ویژه وی آی پی"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/volleyball" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/special_products_horizontal_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/special_products_title"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_products_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/special_products_horizontal_recyclerview"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="#f1f1f1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="محصولات جدید وی آی پی"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/volleyball" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/new_products_horizontal_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="700dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/new_products_title"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_load_categories"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_load_categories"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="لطفا منتظر بمانید ..."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my fragment :

```
package com.gladcherry.vipiranian.activityformain;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks2;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.Animations.DescriptionAnimation;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.TextSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx;
import com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.OnShowcaseEventListener;
import com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView;
import com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.targets.ViewTarget;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.PercentFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.gladcherry.vipiranian.Adapter.CategoriesDataAdapter;
import com.gladcherry.vipiranian.Adapter.ProductsDataAdapter;
import com.gladcherry.vipiranian.MaterialSearchViewPersian;
import com.gladcherry.vipiranian.Model.CategoryModel;
import com.gladcherry.vipiranian.Model.DetailsProjectData;
import com.gladcherry.vipiranian.R;
import com.rd.PageIndicatorView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/**
 * Created by gladcherry on 9/30/17.
 */

public class MainViPFragment extends Fragment
        implements OnShowcaseEventListener {
    ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    int level = 0;
    GridView gridView;
    private Button inviteButton;
    private static String getCategoriesApiUrl;
    private Dialog loader;
    private Button ChangeCity, EditProfile;
    private ShowcaseView sv;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    private MaterialSearchViewPersian searchView;
    private ProgressBar loadCategories;
    RequestQueue queue;
    TextView textView;
    List<CategoryModel> SliderImages;

    //private PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView;
    //private SliderLayout sliderLayout;
    private RelativeLayout Loader;
    private List<DetailsProjectData> specialProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<DetailsProjectData> newProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProductsDataAdapter SpecialDataAdapter;
    private ProductsDataAdapter NewDataAdapter;
    private RecyclerView specialRecyclerView; private RecyclerView newRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_store_categories, container, false);

        makeJsonArrayRequest();
        return layout;
    }

    public void createValidation(String title, String msg) {
        final Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.PauseDialog);
        builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setContentView(R.layout.dialogforvalidations);
        TextView text = (TextView) builder.findViewById(R.id.error_msg);
        text.setText(msg);
        Button close_dialog = (Button) builder.findViewById(R.id.close_btn_dialog);
        close_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                builder.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // display dialog
        builder.show();
    }

    private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {
        // Get UserId if current user has been registered or logged in
        String UserIdSplash = "";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Authentication", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userId = prefs.getString("UserName", null);
        if (userId != null) {
            UserIdSplash = userId;
        }
        // Get UserId if current user has been registered or logged in

        // Get Guest Guid if Guest has been logged in as guest before
        String GuidSplash = "";
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Authentication", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String Guid = sharedPreferences.getString("Guid", null);
        if (Guid != null) {
            GuidSplash = Guid;
        }
        // Get Guest Guid if Guest has been logged in as guest before

        //OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
        getCategoriesApiUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.base_url);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getCategoriesApiUrl, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String State = response.get("Status").toString();
                            if (!State.equals("1")) {
                                Loader.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
                                createValidation("  خطای سیستم  ", response.get("Text").toString());
                            } else {
                                Loader.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
                                SliderImages = new ArrayList<>();
                                //pageIndicatorView.setCount(response.getJSONArray("Sliders").length());
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.getJSONArray("Sliders").length(); i++) {
                                    SliderImages.add(
                                            new CategoryModel(
                                                    response.getJSONArray("Sliders").getJSONObject(i).get("Image").toString(),
                                                    "  وی آی پی | ViP ",
                                                    response.getJSONArray("Sliders").getJSONObject(i).get("Id").toString())
                                    );
                                }
JSONArray SpecialProducts = response.getJSONArray("SpecialProducts");
                                for (int i = 0; i < SpecialProducts.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject currentProduct = SpecialProducts.getJSONObject(i);
                                    specialProducts.add(new DetailsProjectData(currentProduct.getString("Id"), currentProduct.getString("PersianName"), currentProduct.getString("Image"), currentProduct.get("UnitPrice").toString(), currentProduct.get("PriceWithDiscount").toString(), currentProduct.get("Discount").toString(), "", "", "", ""));
                                }
                                SpecialDataAdapter = new ProductsDataAdapter(getActivity(), specialProducts);
                                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                                        = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                specialRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.special_products_horizontal_recyclerview);
                                specialRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                specialRecyclerView.setAdapter(SpecialDataAdapter);
                                specialRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


                                JSONArray NewProducts = response.getJSONArray("NewestProducts");
                                for (int i = 0; i < NewProducts.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject currentProduct = NewProducts.getJSONObject(i);
                                    newProducts.add(new DetailsProjectData(currentProduct.getString("Id"), currentProduct.getString("PersianName"), currentProduct.getString("Image"), currentProduct.get("UnitPrice").toString(), currentProduct.get("PriceWithDiscount").toString(), currentProduct.get("Discount").toString(), "", "", "", ""));
                                }
                                NewDataAdapter = new ProductsDataAdapter(getActivity(), newProducts);
                                LinearLayoutManager newlayoutManager
                                        = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                newRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.new_products_horizontal_recyclerview);
                                newRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(newlayoutManager);
                                newRecyclerView.setAdapter(NewDataAdapter);
                                newRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

                   }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (ex.getMessage() != null) {
                                Log.d("exception", ex.getMessage());
                            }
                            Loader.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error != null && error.getMessage() != null) {
                    Log.w("VolleyError", error.getMessage());
                    VolleyLog.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
                //loadCategories.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                createValidation("پیام سیستم", "لطفا اتصال اینترنت خود را بررسی نمایید .");
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new

                DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);

    }

    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewShow(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewTouchBlocked(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You removed all images AND image loading and animation calls?

Comment: @Barns yes , i removed all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was because of 2 lines that i was added to the manifest to prevent from android out of memory exception ...

remove these two lines and every thing well be ok :

android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

i hope this answer going to help you ...

Answer (score 0):

do the height of relative layout ="wrap_content" instead of match parent , also of scrollview.